# Java stream, difference between with and without forEach

Tags: java, java-stream

What is the difference between with **(*)** `forEach` and without? What is the output and why?  I know without `forEach` nothing will be printed...but why peek is needed?

As I know for `peek` you have to do something with the resulting stream for `System.out.println` to do anything... however it doesn't seems to be done here, and it still runs....

```
public class NaturalNumbers
       implements Supplier<Integer> {
 private int i = 0;
 public Integer get() { return ++i; }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
 Stream<Integer> s =
                Stream.generate(new NaturalNumbers());

 s.limit(5)
  .peek( System.out::println )
  .forEach( System.out::println );/// ׂ (*)
{
```

Comment: *What is the output*: why don't you run the code and see by yourself? Then read the documentation and understand why? What are you expecting to happen when you remove forEach or peek, and what happens instead?

Comment: ji think you must check first about side effects of `for each` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`peek` is just a way to *peek* inside the stream, it doesn't change it but the function in peek will receive all the elements that are in the stream.

`forEach` is an terminal operation that will consume all the data in the stream and return `void`.

The result of the above code will be each number printed twice, when you remove `peek` you will get the numbers printed only once.

If you remove `forEach` you wont' get any output because stream won't execute the actions until the terminal operation (like e.g. `forEach`, `count`) is encountered.

Comment: When you remove the `forEach` you will get no numbers printed, because there is no terminal action consuming items from the stream.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Right I forgot about that, updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

There's a notion of terminal and intermediate operations.
Terminal operations are the final step - they cause all intermediate operations to be processed. Peek is not a terminal operation.

```
Stream.of("one", "two", "three", "four")
          .filter(e -> e.length() > 3)
          .peek(e -> System.out.println("Filtered value: " + e))
          .map(String::toUpperCase)
          .peek(e -> System.out.println("Mapped value: " + e))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And yes, I'd recommend you to look inside javadocs of method peek:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

Also, read this document
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/

How to know if a method is a terminal operation or an intermediate? As simple, as it can be - intermediate operations always return Stream class, while terminal operations can return various different objects - Optional classes, some collections, primitives and so on.